# closure compiler externs solves an issue but i didn't understand why?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I compile my source with closure compiler and when i call a function that got an event object from network the application throws an error in console.

The function called is:

```
/**
 * @param {goog.events.Event} event Socket.io-Wrapper Event.
 */
de.my.app.admin.prototype.onSaved = function(event){ 
  var category = event.data[0].category; //<-- here it throws the error because category get compiled.
  var id       = event.data[0].id;
  var oldid    = event.data[0].oldid;
[...]
}
```

the event object looks like this

```
{ data:{
    0: {
      category: 'someString',
      id:       5,
      oldid:    -5
  } } 
[...someMoreValuesAddedBySocketIO...]
}
```

**that is the behavior i expected.**

now i add an externs declaration like this to my externs file **but i didn't alter the type declaration of the `@param` at the function** and the error disappears:

```
var xterns;
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   category : string,
 *   oldid    : number,
 *   id       : number
 * }}
 */
xterns.NOTUSEDNAME;

/**
 * @type {string}
 */
xterns.NOTUSEDNAME.prototype.category;

/**
 * @type {number}
 */

xterns.NOTUSEDNAME.prototype.oldid;

/**
 * @type {number}
 */
xterns.NOTUSEDNAME.prototype.id;
```

In short: I have a `@param {goog.events.Event} event` declaration and an extern for `xterns.NOTUSEDNAME` solves the compiler problems...
Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common misconception. Closure-compiler will not rename a property if **any** extern object contains a property of the same name. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#some-of-my-properties-are-getting-renamed-but-some-arent-why). If the type based optimizations are enabled, then this is no longer true and I would expect your code to break again.

To make this code type safe and compile without warnings, you would need to either:

1. Reference the data properties using quoted syntax `event.data[0]['category']`. Your properties will never be renamed by the compiler using this method (which is often used by JSON Data).
2. Extend the `goog.events.Event` type with a custom object that defines the data object as a strongly typed array.

Example:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.events.Event}
 */
de.my.app.AdminEvent = function() {};
goog.inherits(de.my.app.AdminEvent, goog.events.Event);

/** @type {Array.<{category:string, id:number, oldid:number}>} */
de.my.app.AdminEvent.prototype.data = [];
```

Depending on your exact situation, an interface might be a better option.